# How to explain the why here?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Reading Lebesgue outer measure of Lebesgue Measure Chapter from Carothers' Real Analysis and some properties and their proofs are here:

[image]

Basically, I can't understand the proof for reverse inequality of (vi). I've no ideal how to explain the "why" there. Besides, what's the relationship between $[a_n,b_n]$ and $I_n$ or $J_n$(Is $I_n$ picked up from the set of {$[a_n,b_n]$ | $n∈ \mathbb N$} )?

Thanks all.

Add:

Definition of Carothers' Outer Measure
[image]

Comment: If $m^*(E)=\infty$, from the first inequality, we have the other side is equal to $\infty$ as well, so we are done

Comment: @Alan: Ohhhh, Yes^_^

Comment: @Alan: Is $I_n$ chosen from the set of {$[a_n,b_n]$ | $n∈ \mathbb N$}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse inequality of (vi) is:
$$m^*(E)\ge{\rm inf}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n-a_n) : \, E\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(a_n,b_n)\right\} .$$
The reason for (why?) is: if the LHS is infinity, there is nothing to prove.

As for the rest of the proof of (vi), the collection of intervals $(I_n)$ exists by definition of outer measure. (I'm assuming that the Carothers definition of outer measure doesn't require the intervals $(I_n)$ to be open--they can be closed, half-open, etc.) Then the $(J_n)$ are selected to be *open* intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ such that each $I_n\subset J_n$ and $J_n$ is slightly longer than $I_n$. It is always possible to find such ($J_n$). For example, the closed interval $[u,v]$ is contained within the open interval $(u-\delta,v+\delta)$.

Note: (vi) is saying that in the definition of outer measure you can require  each covering interval $I_n$ to be open. In some treatments of measure theory,  outer measure is defined with that requirement right off the bat.

EDIT: Just saw the edit to your OP and it confirms my assumption of the Carothers def of outer measure.

Comment: $I_n$ is some $[an_,b_n]$? Why do you prefer $I_n$ to be open? why not closed?

Comment: Each interval $I_n$ has unnamed endpoints. The $J_n$ have named endpoints $a_n$ and $b_n$. The Carothers def of outer measure allows the $I_n$ to be closed, or open. But (vi) is saying that you can always satisfy the definition by restricting attention to open $I_n$ -- that way you don't have to worry about the shape of the endpoints of $I_n$ (is it closed on one end, open on the other, do I have to handle the four cases separately, etc.?)

Comment: What is LHS above?

Comment: Sorry, LHS = left hand side = $m^*(E)$. If the left hand side is infinity then always LHS $\ge$ RHS.

Comment: Make sense^_^ Thank you grand_chat

Comment: Seems (vi) can always be used to calculate inner measure of a set, right?

Comment: Yes, provided (vi) gives you a finite value for $m^*(E)$, you can use it to get the inner measure of the complement of $E$. What definition are you using for inner measure?

Comment: inner measure of E defined as $m_*(E)$ = b - a - $m^*([a,b] - E)$

Comment: There you go. Yes, you can get $m_*$ by calculating $m^*$ on the complementary set, using any method you can.