# How will m*(rE) behave?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $rE ＝\{rx: x\in E\}$, what is $m^*(rE)$ in terms of $m^*(E)$?

Intuitively, I think $m^*(rE)\leq r\times m^*(E)$. However I've no idea how to prove it?

Add:
Definition of Lebesgue Outer Measure is here: [How to explain the why here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198465/how-to-explain-the-why-here)

Update:
My intuitiveness can be incorrect. Actually, $m^*(rE) = r\times m^*(E)$. Still, I've no idea how to find a complete proof.

Comment: You should specify that you are working on the line, and that $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: Anyway, prove your conjecture for intervals and then see what you can do in general. I think you should find that if $ E $ is a disjoint union of intervals, then you have equality until $ r $ is so big that they overlap. At that point you will "lose" measure, which should give the inequality. Now try to extend this.

Comment: @Ian Why wouldn't the question make sense in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @neuguy The scaling is different: dilations scale volume by $ r^n $ (the determinant of $ rI_n $).

Comment: @Ian Yes, but scaling by $r^1$ was merely the OP's guess. For all we know he isn't familiar with how scaling works in $n$ dimensions. The problem itself makes no reference to the dimension of the underlying space.

Comment: @neuguy OK, I made some assumptions about the problem context. The point is that Frank_W should clarify these aspects of the context.

Comment: @lan: sorry lan, I've added the definition of Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: @lan: What's the example for "<"?

Comment: @Ian: I don't think your 2nd comment is correct. What is the example for "<"?

Comment: @Frank_W I think I made a mistake, because I had thought your operation was a pure dilation but actually it is not unless the interval is centered at zero. I was visualizing the operation as just stretching the interval while holding its center fixed, which it doesn't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right (as long as the underlying space is $\mathbb R$) but you get the reverse inequality more or less for free:
$$
m(E) = m \left(\frac 1r rE \right) \le \frac 1r m(rE)$$ so that $rm(E) \le m(rE)$.

Comment: I think my guess is incorrect. I cannot find a example for "<". How about yours?

Comment: If $E$ is any set, measurable or not, then $m^*(rE) = rm^*(E)$ for all $r>0$. You won't be able to find an example for $<$.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: Ohhh, awesome. I got your idea. Reverse inequality is working simultaneously and then $m^*(rE) = r \times m^*(E)$.